# Forever can't start blessed-contrib examples

Tags: node.js, bash, terminal, forever, blessed

i'm trying out Forever, very popular package, so i decided to try some existents scrips.
For example the blessed-contrib examples, the dashboard.js in particular, since i would like to have some always running monitor with terminal interface for a kiosk.
https://github.com/yaronn/blessed-contrib

But it just does not works, here the messages i get:

```
$ forever start donut.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: donut.js
```

The first two are just waring, but the process end without a reason i can get.

Any clue?

Comment: Hey, have you been able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the script should be running already. It is because `forever start` runs the node.js script in the background.
The command `forever list` can list out all the process running by the forever. You can see if everything works or not through this command. Also, you will be able to see the location of the logs after the `forever list` command executed.

Comment: You were actually right, only thing: how can I make it running the app not in background then but on a specific terminal that i want?

Comment: I think it is not possible. At least I don't know there is a way to do that. However, if you want to keep monitor at your logs (i.e. console.log() outputs), you can use `forever list` to find out the location of the logs. Then, use the command `tail -f /path/to/the/file.log`.

Comment: No, actually i want to do a kiosk that visualize a command line interface. It works with a start script, but would be great to use Forever, is there a way to make it works?